# Zabbix: мониторинг LSI MegaRAID на сервере с ESXI

Tags: vmware, zabbix, raid

Появилась необходимость мониторить с помощью сервера Zabbix (с промежуточным Zabbix-proxy) LSI MegaRAID (сервер Supermicro Super Server) рейд-массив на сервере с ESXi 6.5.

Проблема в том, что на самом ESXi-хосте нельзя поставить софт вроде megacli, zabbix-agent или что-то вроде. На данный момент смог установить только пакет lsi_provider. Напрямую с сервера Zabbix могу забирать информацию о состоянии вентиляторов, батарей и прочего, но информацию по рейду не забирает.

Кто-нибудь настраивал подобный мониторинг?

Answer (score 1):

Если актуально - перепилил темплейт и скрипты мониторинга MegaRAID под ESXi
https://github.com/ghost9777/zabbix_megaraid_esxi